# Which annotate the relationship allow Jackson to better handle the relation ? @Json

Tags: json, spring, spring-mvc, jackson, spring-data-jpa

Which annotate the relationship allow Jackson to better handle the relation, for save Click ? How change request:

> { "idBanner": 2, "fullnameClient": "Maria"}

`@JsonManagedReference, @JsonBackReference,@JsonIdentityInfo,@JsonIgnore`...
Working format-request (save Click):

Comment: { "idBanner": 1, "fullnameClient": "Maria"} - this structure acceptable ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@RequestParam` is used to map just request parameters. For example, it will work for requests like `POST /sentemail?fullnameClient=vov&idBanner=1`

To get request body you should use `@RequestBody` annotation.

**Important notice**
I would recommended don't use models (entities) for requests and responses, because it increases a coupling between your business logic and external contract Rest API. For example, in future you will not able to change model without changing of external contract and vise versa.

But if you still want to use entities as request/response body, I would recommend taking a look on [Jackson MixIns](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonMixInAnnotations). It helps to have separate mapping for Jackson and Entities.

Comment: BannerInfo not Entity ?

Comment: @Query(value = "insert into Click (fullnameClient, idBanner) VALUES (:fullnameClient, :idBanner)", nativeQuery = true)
    String sentsaveclick(@Param("fullnameClient") String fullnameClient, @Param("idBanner") long idBanner);

Comment: Change ? @Query(value = "insert into Click (fullnameClient, idBanner) VALUES (:fullnameClient, :idBanner)", nativeQuery = true)
    String sentsaveclick(@RequestBody BannerInfo bannerInfo);

Comment: @NewWave no, this is just for request body. I would recommended don't use models (entities) for requests and responses, because it increases a coupling between your business logic and external contract Rest API. For example, in future you will not able to change model without changing of external contract and vise versa

Comment: BannerInfo наследовался от Entity Banner ?

Comment: @NewWave I've updated the answer with an example for your service usage. If you still want to use entities as request/response body, I would recommend taking a look on http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonMixInAnnotations

Comment: good advice, "this is just for request body. I would recommended don't use models (entities) for requests and responses, because it increases a coupling between your business logic and external contract Rest API. For example, in future you will not able to change model without changing of external contract and vise versa"

Comment: i just began. i use controller,service, serviceImpl, repository

Comment: My Click,Banner this Entity.(also i have layer entity,service, repo...). Your Banner,BannerInfo that of the layer ?

Comment: @NewWave presentation layer, this is just about how user will see or pass data

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134370/discussion-between-new-wave-and-vlad-bochenin).